# How is UTF-16 with big endian BOM (FEFF) stored in a little endian machine?

Tags: unicode, endianness, utf-16, utf

From my understanding, the endianness of UTF-16 is independent from the endianness of the host architecture.
Let's take the character 0x0042 (the letter "D") saved in a file for example. In big endian UTF-16 (UTF-16BE) file format, it'll be encoded as:

`00 42`

But if this file is created and saved on a little endian machine, it will be stored as:

`42 00`

Now, let's say the user opens the file again and the file processor starts reading the byte stream. The file processor will assume the bytes are stored in big endian order (because of the UTF-16BE format), but the byte stream order is actually little endian. Instead of a value of 0x0044 (i.e letter "D"), it will read it as 0x4400 (a [Hans](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4400/index.htm) character) Won't this mess up how the file appears to the user? In other words, what is the use of the utf-16 BE/LE format if, eventually, it's the host's endianess that really matters?

Comment: You're overthinking this.  A file is a file.  The same bytes should always be presented to your application in the same order, regardless of your platform's CPU architecture.  What about Java class files (0xCAFEBABE), Gif files ("GIF89a") or .png files ("PNG\r\n\032\n"), to give just a few examples?

Comment: A file is a series of bytes, so ordered bytes, and independent of architecture/endianess. Endianess is important when you interpret the data, and we can handle this very well (we are mostly using x86 CPU which have a different endianness then TCP/IP [so internet]). Editor can convert encoding (and probably for code efficiency an editor use internally only one format, just when it read a file it put the right byte on right place). Protocol format, internal format and CPU format are independent (and converted). We often exchange numbers at text string (of ASCII digits): reader will convert

Comment: To answer the actual questions (last two sentences): 1. Sure it will; 2. File-formats are of no use, if the file-content doesn't match the specification. Nonetheless, `UTF-16 with BOM`  can be read on any platform if the reader process swaps bytes if necessary (i.e. if platform endianness differs from file endiannes (which can be find out from the BOM))

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers do not really answer the question.  If the file is written on a host with a different endian architecture to the host where the file is read, then there *is* potential for the file to appear corrupt to the user.

As the questioner says, the byte order of the character "D" will be different depending on where the file is written.  For example, running the following command on a UTF8 terminal to convert the character "D" to UTF-16 and then dump the resulting value in hex:

```
 printf "D" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16 |od -t xC
```

...will produce this output on a big-endian AIX host:

```
0000000  00 44
```

...and this output on a little-endian Linux host:

```
0000000 44 00
```

To solve this problem the Unicode standard provides a special code point U+FEFF  which can be (optionally) used at the beginning of a Unicode text as a Byte Order Mark.

If UTF-16 text begins `FE FF` then the text has a big-endian encoding.  If a system reads the BOM as the non-character `FF FE` then the system will need to reverse the bytes in order to correctly process the text.

If there is no BOM at the beginning of the text (but the text is known to be Unicode) then the Unicode FAQ states that the text should be iterpreted as big-endian.

For more infomation see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM

https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch02.pdf#G27981